# Using Perl here-document results in "Can't find string terminator "EOF" anywhere before EOF"

Tags: perl, heredoc

I've been trying to use [Here-documents](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#%3c%3cEOF), but it's not working. What might be wrong? Am I missing something obvious?

This is the entire contents of the file I'm trying to run (there are no spaces, or tabs anywhere):

```
print<<EOF;
text
EOF
```

I'm running it by saving it in [Notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29) or [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) as a file called *3.pl*.

Then by going into the DOS window under Windows 7
and typing `perl 3.pl` I get this message:

> Can't find string terminator "EOF"
> anywhere before EOF at 3.pl line 1.

Comment: How are you attempting to run it?

Comment: How the heck are you creating files without newlines at the end of them? That messes up all kinds of things.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Make sure your file has an empty line at the end. This should be four lines:

```
print<<EOF;
text
EOF 
#or a comment here works too ;)
```

Comment: yeah that works now - it just needed a blank newline at the end. Thanks. Why couldn't it say that in perldoc?

Comment: [Actually, it does](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html): `If the terminating identifier is on the last line of the program, you must be sure there is a newline after it; otherwise, Perl will give the warning Can't find string terminator "END" anywhere before EOF....`

Comment: oh ok - just seems rather buried  and it really should be here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#Why-don't-my-%3c%3cHERE-documents-work%3f in the Why doesn't my here-document work? section. Furthermore Can't find string terminator "END" anywhere before EOF.... is just a stupid way of saying "I can't handle a here-document at the end of a file". Use diagnostics was no help. Have to hate perl sometimes, but at least there's this place to make up for it.

Comment: That's a valid suggestion. I've mailed the mailing-list asking it to be added to the perlfaq.

Comment: And this place is just one of the many places - the perlmonks website would have surely have helped you as well. Their chatbox is filled with smart people, and if noone's around you can still post your question in a new node.

Comment: Thank you for helping me and for sending the email.

Comment: It's because most of the time there are others things at the end of the script.

Comment: Many editors add a trailing line terminator if you don't add it yourself, so many people don't notice or have this problem. It's documented, although I'll add it to the FAQ. Note that you shouldn't stop at the FAQ if you don't get your answer. Go to the right part of the docs that explain it in full.

Comment: @brian: I know, but with the cryptic error message, the user even use diagnostics, and reading the F.A.Q., there are already 3 sources of information that didn't explain the problem... Thanks for adding it to the F.A.Q.!

Comment: The one canonical place for here document information does explain it though. Just increase your doc-fu by going to the source instead of the second-level docs that swirl around the source.

Comment: @Konerak Good point when checking your excellent comment, emmm, is this a "feature" in Perl? Or just something we need to remember...